# Ordenar lista de tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito ordenar una lista de registros de una tabla relacional.Como muestro los registros

```
@foreach($reservas as $reserva)                           
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $reserva->Vendedor->ven_nombre }}</td>
         <td>{{ $reserva->res_stoauto }}</td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Asi paso los datos

```
public function reservas(){

    $reservas = Reserva::where('res_tipo',5)
            ->where('res_anulada','<>',1)
            ->orderby('res_vendedor','ASC')
            ->paginate(50);

    return view('bd.reservas',compact('reservas'));
}
```

Y este es mi modelo Reserva

```
public function Vendedor(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendedor', 'res_vendedor', 'ven_codigo')->orderBy('ven_nombre','ASC');
}
```

Como puedo ordenar la lista por el nombre alfabetico de los vendedores, el campo del nombre seria ven_nombre

Comment: No entiendo la duda, ¿quieres agrupar por las 2 columnas, no obtienes el resultado deseado?.....

Comment: Ordenar las listas por el campo ven_nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplica un `join` a tu estructura de este modo:

```
$reservas = Reserva::join('vendedores', 'vendedores.id', '=', 'reserva.vendedor_id')
                    ->where('res_tipo',5)
                    ->where('res_anulada','<>',1)
                    ->orderBy('vendedores.ven_nombre','DESC')
                    ->paginate(50);
```

**Aclaraciones**

- Usa `'vendedores', 'vendedores.id', '=', 'reversa.vendedor_id'` para indicar la igualdad que debe existir entre las tablas y poder crear el `join`
- Usa `->orderby('vendedores.ven_nombre','ASC')` para indicar el ordenamiento, por defecto es `ASC` así que como segundo argumento puedes pasar `DESC`

Comment: Mil gracias por todo. Funciono de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar una consulta compuesta donde en la segunda tabla en tu caso **(Vendedor)** le pongas `orderBy('ven_nombre','ASC')` algo como esto:

```
    $reservas = DB::table('reserva')
    ->join('vendedor', function($join) use ($vendedor)
    {
        $join->on('reserva.id', '=', 'vendedor.id')
             ->orderBy('vendedor.ven_nombre','ASC');
    });
```

Comment: esa variable es si deseas hacer un filtro adicional, por ejemplo, yo he trabajado con algo como esto:  $query = DB::table('persons')
        ->join('companies', function($join) use ($company)
        {
            $join->on('persons.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                 ->where('companies.id', '=', $company);